# Interactive SendKeys PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, sendkeys

Not by choice I had to port a Sendkeys script to run with PowerShell. We use this application that's backed up daily and the only way is to do it manually through the application. So to avoid having to sit there and do it manually every day, I created a Sendkeys script and it works without a hitch when I run it manually. However, the problem is when I schedule it. It does not open the application so the Sendkeys command are worthless.
In Task Scheduler I have "powershell.exe" under Program/script and then under Add arguments (optional) I have "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass  c:\users\User1\desktop\MIP_Backup_NpsSqlSys.ps1".
I also added the folder and the exec to the windows 10 path and verified it is there. Any help whatsoever would be welcome.
This is the Sendkeys script. It opens the application, clicks on the Menu and selects backup then the DB to backup. When it is done, it sends me an email.
I do have start-sleep command in between but removed them to make now to make it shorter.

```
    'Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\MIP\Progs\AcctAdv.exe"
    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
    $wshell.AppActivate('Open Organization')
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('admin{TAB}')
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('PASSWORD{TAB}')
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('DATABASE{ENTER}')
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('%F{DOWN 2}{ENTER}')
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{ENTER}')
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{ENTER}')
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('admin{TAB}')
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('%{F4}')
    $line1 = "MIP Backup."
    $line2 = "Check the MIP backup to ensure it ran."
    $line3 = "\\Server\d$\1-backups "
    $line4 = "Name."
    Send-MailMessage -smtpServer IP_ADDRESS_HERE -To MyEmailAddressHere.com -From MIP_Backup@One.local -Subject $line1 -Body  $line2`n`n$line3`n`n$line4
```

Comment: Use powershell.exe to launch it, instead of start-process, using this instead: `Powershell.exe -file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MIP\Progs\AcctAdv.exe"` Or you could also try this: `& Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\MIP\Progs\AcctAdv.exe"`

Comment: Let me try it.  I'll let you know.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the help.

This is how I got it working.

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "AcctAdv.exe"

Wscript.Sleep 2000
objShell.SendKeys "USER NAME"
Wscript.Sleep 1000
objShell.SendKeys "{tab}"
Wscript.Sleep 1000
objShell.SendKeys "PASSWORD"
Wscript.Sleep 1000
objShell.SendKeys "{tab}"
Wscript.Sleep 1000
objShell.SendKeys "{tab}"
Wscript.Sleep 1000
objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Wscript.Sleep 2000
objShell.SendKeys ("%F")
Wscript.Sleep 2000
objShell.SendKeys "B"
Wscript.Sleep 3000
objShell.SendKeys ("DB NAME")
Wscript.Sleep 1000
objShell.SendKeys "{tab}"
objShell.SendKeys "{tab}"
Wscript.Sleep 1000
objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Do Until Success = True
  Success = objShell.AppActivate("Finance")
  Wscript.Sleep 1000
Loop
objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Wscript.Sleep 2000
objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
objShell.SendKeys ("%{F4}")
```

Then I scheduled it and it works fine.

Thanks again.